# How can I visualize data based on number ranges?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, gephi, sigma.js, bigdata

I'm attempting to create a visualization of a .CSV  file with 1.2 million lines, similar to the following:

```
 source        ,     destination
12.251.512     ,     12.623.743
51.734.312     ,     23.233.991
6334.6231.123  ,     42.532.54453
```

(using 40-100k lines for testing purposes)

After much research, I've decided to try out Gephi and probably sigma.JS to implement the visual data into a website. (exporting .GEXF graphs from gephi into sigma.JS to use with web)

Since 1.2 million lines is very hard to visualize, my thought was to create an input box where a user can enter a single address or a range of numbers. Then take those numbers and create a mini-visualization based on that range.

So here is my problem, I have searched sigma.js for an example similar to what I need, with a box to enter ranges or individual values to create miniature graphs based on the larger dataset. But it seems like this may not be possible.

Ideally, I'd like to have a box that can search a range, and display the whole data-set graph if need be.

Is this possible using Gephi and sigmajs? If not, does anyone have any recommendations for tackling this type of project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend D3 library. I'd look at it https://d3js.org/

The biggest part of the job is to group your data in a way that makes sense and make sure that you feed it in JSON format. 1.2 million rows is not much of data as long as your growing makes sense. Also, I highly recommend adding filters in order for your audience to be able to slice and dice the data the way they want.